# Refactoring code dependent on external class

Tags: java, refactoring, clean-code, code-smell

I have a class similar to ServletFilter which has multiple validation on the input request

```
class TokenHandler implements SomeHandler{
  Response handle(Request request){
    if(paramXMissing(request)){
       return new Response(); // empty response
    }
    if(paramYGreaterThan100(Request request)){
       return new Response(); // empty response
    }
   //some more similar validation on request


  }
}
```

`request` parameter can be an instance of any subtype of `Request`. As most of the validation methods depend on `Request` instead of the Handler, this seems more like *feature envy* code smell. Had `Request` been a normal domain object I would have just *Moved method* to that class. But in this case, how do I refactor this code  (*Long method*)?
I am not sure if introducing a new Validator class would be a right choice.

Edit

---

I don't have just the validation, but also additional processing on request object, for instance, remove particular parameter from query string.

I actually think that introducing new classes for each specification would be an overkill. Is it really required? Any other alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style for control flow with validation checks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148849/style-for-control-flow-with-validation-checks)

Comment: ...as for `Request` I would most likely pass it via constructor parameter into that `Specification` class discussed in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148855/31260)

Comment: Does this mean that I have to create different `specification` classes for each condition? Doesn't it sound like an overkill?

Comment: Are you able to create a subclass of Request, and add your validation functions to that instead?

Comment: you create one specification class for all conditions and one instance of that class per request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an interface for the Validator and create a list of specialized Vatidator objects:

```
 class TokenHandler implements SomeHandler{
   interface Validator{
     boolean isInvalid(Request request);
  }
  private final List<Validator> validators = Arrays.asList(
      (Validator)request->paramXMissing(request), 
      (Validator)request->paramYGreaterThan100(request),
      // Checks could also be implemented as separate classes or enum... 
    );

  Response handle(Request request){
    for(Validator validator : validators){
      if(validator.isInvalid(request)){
         return new Response(); // empty response
      }
    }
    // continue for valid response
  }
}
```