# How to validate many JSON fields without cluttering up the code with if-checks on each field?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, json

I have a class which contains various fields and they could be accessed with the help of getters and setters like the following

```java
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int sibblingsCount;
    private String elderSibblingName;
    private String youngerSibblingName;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setSibblingsCount(int count) {
        this.sibblingsCount = count;
    }
    public int getSibblingsCount() {
        return this.sibblingsCount;
    }

    public void setElderSibblingName(String name) {
        this.elderSibblingName = name;
    }
    public String getElderSibblingName() {
        return this.elderSibblingName;
    }

    public void setYoungerSibblingName(String name) {
        this.youngerSibblingName = name;
    }
    public void getYoungerSibblingName() {
        return this.youngerSibblingName;
    }

    public String getStudentDetails() {    
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
            json.put("name", this.name);
        }

        if(this.age != 0) {
            json.put("age", this.age);
        }

        if(this.sibblingsCount != 0) {
            json.put("sibblingsCount", this.sibblingsCount);
        }

        if(this.elderSibblingName != null && !this.elderSibblingName.isEmpty()) {
            json.put("elderSibblingName", this.elderSibblingName);
        }

        if(this.youngerSibblingName != null && !this.youngerSibblingName.isEmpty() {
            json.put("youngerSibblingName", this.youngerSibblingName);
        }
        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

All I need is to pack the valid fields in the class `Student`. The field is said to be valid when it contains some value in it. Say `age` should not be `0` and it must be a valid number. Say `elderSibblingName` it must not be null or empty. How to check for valid fields while packing the resultant JSON?

It is really painful to check for validity against each and every filed of the class which makes the code looks clumsy when there are too many fields in the class.

Comment: Is there a reason you're reinventing the wheel, rather than using one of the numerous JSON libraries already available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style for control flow with validation checks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148849/style-for-control-flow-with-validation-checks)

Comment: Why is this a JSON problem? Isn't an object valid or invalid at a point in time, both as individual properties as they are set and as a while (siblingCount==0 and elderSiblingName not null) the validity is a general property no matter how the object is populated/constructed.

Comment: I'm with Philip and LotzInSpace. This sounds like a job for the [Bean validation API](http://beanvalidation.org/).

Comment: http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're bothered by your repetitive checks, extract them into a function to make them less repetitive. For example:

```
private static <T> void putIf(JsonObject json, String name, T value, Predicate<T> isValid) {
  if (isValid.test(value)) json.put(name, value);
}

private boolean isNonEmpty(String s) {
  return s != null && !s.isEmpty();
}

private boolean isNonZero(int i) {
  return i != 0;
}

public String getStudentDetails() {    
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    putIf(json, "name", name, x -> isNonEmpty(x));
    putIf(json, "age", age, x -> isNonZero(x));
    putIf(json, "siblingsCount", siblingsCount, x -> isNonZero(x));
    putIf(json, "elderSiblingName", elderSiblingName, x -> isNonEmpty(x));
    putIf(json, "youngerSiblingName", youngerSiblingName, x -> isNonEmpty(x));

    return json.toString();
}
```

However, that doesn't address a fundamental problem of your class: The fields can contain invalid values! In many cases, that can be avoided by fully initializing the object in a constructor, and avoiding setters unless they also fully validate their values.

If your validation constraints are more complicated, you can also create your own types that represent a particular validation constraint, e.g.:

```
final class Name {
  private final String name;

  public Name(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty())
      throw ...;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String get() { return name; }
}
```

If a value has a particular meaning in your domain model, you should prefer a simple class like this over built-in or primitive types.

You can now use that class throughout your code, though you still have to check that the object is non-null:

```
public class Student {

    private Name name;
    ...
    private Name elderSibblingName;
    private Name youngerSibblingName;

    public Name getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;  // assuming null is valid
    }

    ...

    public String getStudentDetails() {    
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        if(name != null) {
            json.put("name", name.get());
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using lambdas to make the code easier to read. Not a fan of the rest, though.

Comment: Nitpicking: You can make your utility functions static as the don't use `this` for anything

Comment: @amon: In Haskell you would simplify `\x -> isNonEmpty x` to `isNonEmpty` (pointfree style). Is it possible to do the same in Java with `x -> isNonEmpty(x)`?

Comment: @Giorgio You can use *method references* in Java, like `this::isNonEmpty`. However, I find those harder to teach than explicit lambdas. Java cannot use a method name on its own since variables and methods live in different namespaces: the syntax `isNonEmpty` would always be a variable or field, whereas `isNonEmpty()` or `this::isNonEmpty` always refers to a method. That makes Java a bit clumsy for functional programming.

Comment: @Giorgio since this got bumped, you can also declare your predicate as a variable instead of a function like this: `private Predicate<String> isNonEmpty = s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty();` and then you can refer to it by the variable name which is similar.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, the particular sort of cluttering taking place during validation is because the code is usually temporally coupled. It's hard to read and hard to maintain. Being a fan of declarative code, I implement validation declaratively as well.

Here is an example. Suppose we have the following schema:

```
{
    "payment":{
        "card_number":12345612341234,
        "expires_at":"12/29"
    }
}
```

I'd love to have a single expression validating this one. And actually I do have one, here it goes in `result()` method:

```
public class ValidatedRegistrationRequest implements Validatable<RegistrationRequest>
{
    private String jsonRequestString;
    private Connection dbConnection;

    public ValidatedRegistrationRequest(String jsonRequestString, Connection dbConnection)
    {
        this.jsonRequestString = jsonRequestString;
        this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public Result<RegistrationRequest> result() throws Exception
    {
        return
            new FastFail<>(
                new WellFormedJson(
                    new Unnamed<>(Either.right(new Present<>(this.jsonRequestString)))
                ),
                requestJsonObject ->
                    new UnnamedBlocOfNameds<>(
                        List.of(
                            new FastFail<>(
                                new IsJsonObject(
                                    new Required(
                                        new IndexedValue("payment", requestJsonObject)
                                    )
                                ),
                                paymentJsonObject ->
                                    new NamedBlocOfNameds<>(
                                        "payment",
                                        List.of(
                                            new ValidThrueIsNotExpired(
                                                new AsString(
                                                    new Required(
                                                        new IndexedValue("valid_thru", paymentJsonObject)
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            ),
                                            new CardNumberIsNotBlacklisted(
                                                new CardNumberSatisfiesLuhnAlgorithm(
                                                    new Required(
                                                        new IndexedValue("card_number", paymentJsonObject)
                                                    )
                                                ),
                                                this.dbConnection
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        Payment.class
                                    )
                            )
                        ),
                        RegistrationRequest.class
                    )
            )
                .result()
            ;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, softwareengineering can't format code with line numbers. [Here](https://validol.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/how_to_parse_and_validate_json_schema_in_java.html) you can find a line-by-line analysis of what's going on here.

Besides, there is no mutation here. Not a single setter, nowhere. This adds up to overall maintainability.

This approach might deceptively seem like overkill in this relatively simple case. But don't forget about multiple null checks and all the nitty-gritty stuff that goes with validation. Anyways, it truly shines when used with complex json schemas with intricate validation rules.