# How to Replace Many if Statements for many types

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, code-quality, swift-language

I have many dependent statements. What is the best approach to handle these cases dynamically?

Example

```
enum UserType {

    case buyer
    case seller
} 

enum ViewType {

    case active
    case inactive
} 

enum ActionType {

     case buy
     case offer
}
```

These types are retrieved from an API.

I have a matrix of dependent cases. I need to check all types.

```
if userType == UserType.buyer && viewType == ViewType.active && actionType = ActionType.buy {

   // return view
} else if userType == UserType.buyer && viewType == ViewType.active && actionType = ActionType.offer {
   // return view

}else if userType == UserType.seller && viewType == ViewType.active && actionType = ActionType.buy {
   // return view

}else if userType == UserType.seller && viewType == ViewType.active && actionType = ActionType.offer {
   // return view

}else if userType == UserType.buyer && viewType == ViewType.inactive && actionType = ActionType.buy {
   // return view

}else if userType == UserType.buyer && viewType == ViewType.inactive && actionType = ActionType.offer {
   // return view

}
..... too many cases
```

I've tried to handle these cases using a command design pattern but this results in too many cases especially when adding a new `ViewType` or `ActionType`. I need to create 4 classes `buyerNewViewTypeOffer`, `SellerNewViewTypeOffer`, `buyerNewViewTypeBuy`, `SellerNewViewTypeBuy`...

Any idea how to handle these cases dynamically when adding a new type without needing to create many statements or classes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style for control flow with validation checks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148849/style-for-control-flow-with-validation-checks)

Comment: @gnat I think it's not the same I have a dependence of statements the mentioned question has a direct case

Comment: I think this will gravitate toward the expression problem https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-expression-problem-and-its-solutions/

Comment: @jk. i will check

Comment: The code you have is more like a procedural finite state machine than an object oriented solution.  The only difference is that you have complex if structures rather than nested switch statements.

Comment: If this really changes that often and if you really need that flexibility, and if you are getting these from an API, then maybe do something like a table–based (or sparse multidimensional matrix–based) finite state machine. Basically, create something that lets you register a combination of these types as a key (e.g, and ordered tuple), and the handler function or object as a value. You may want to support dispatching on unspecified keys as well, e.g. (buyer, active, *) - the exact details depend on what you need to support. But double check if this approach is not an overkill.

Answer (score 3):

A so-called *"state table"* or *"finite-state machine (FSM)"* design might be helpful here.  The algorithm starts in one "state" and moves to other "states" as time goes on.

When the algorithm is presented with another input or set of inputs, it uses its "current state" and the inputs to *look up in a table* (or some equivalent data structure ...) what to do next.  This consists of an action to be taken, and the next "state" to enter.

A particular benefit of this design, in addition to pushing a lot of the decision-making to a data structure that can be accessed by a small and easily-debugged algorithm, is that it cleanly separates "deciding what to do next" from "doing it."  You can easily expand the behavior of the system without adding complexity to the various moving parts.

> https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/finite-state-machines-theory-and-implementation--gamedev-11867

Answer (score -1):

```
enum UserType {buyer=0,seller=1}
enum ViewType {active=0,inactive=1}
enum ActionType {buy=0,offer=1}

int Action;          
string ActionNumber=((int)UserType.seller).ToString() + ((int)ViewType.active).ToString() +((int)ActionType.buy).ToString();
Action = Convert.ToInt32(ActionNumber, 2);
```

From this u Get a Integer number, store every view according to Integer Number in DB, and from user request show the View as u desire.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Caution: this would fail miserably if you ever needed 10 `UserType`s in the future.

Comment: You can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged so that you can edit your post freely.

Answer (score -1):

maybe have a look at the "expression problem". besides that you could make the code more readable if you would pack every complex condition in a own method with a good name like "isBuyerViewCase" or something like that.